# How to update value from a document in elasticsearch through Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
POST /indexcn/doc/7XYIWHMB6jW2P6mpdcgv/_update
  {
    "doc" : {
    "DELIVERYDATE" : 100
  }
 }
```

I am trying to update the DELIVERYDATE from 0 to 100, but I am getting document missing exception.
How to update the document with a new value?

Here is my index :

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "indexcn",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "7XYIWHMB6jW2P6mpdcgv",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      .......
      .......   
      "DELIVERYDATE" : 0,
   }
```

Comment: The document doesn't seem to exist. What do you get when running `GET /indexcn/doc/7XYIWHMB6jW2P6mpdcgv`?

Comment: #! Deprecation: [types removal] Specifying types in document get requests is deprecated, use the /{index}/_doc/{id} endpoint instead.
{
  "_index" : "indexcn",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "7XYIWHMB6jW2P6mpdcgv",
  "found" : false
}

Comment: See `found: false` the document you're trying to update doesn't exist in your index. You need to index it first, before being able to update it.

Comment: I have updated my index details in the question, could you please tell me if the syntax I'm using is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually got the mapping type wrong (`doc` instead of `_doc`). Try this and it will work:

```
           fix this
              |
              v
POST /indexcn/_doc/7XYIWHMB6jW2P6mpdcgv/_update
{
    "doc" : {
       "DELIVERYDATE" : 100
    }
}
```